# Summing two strings and getting an int value in C

Tags: c, string, ascii, addition

I want to sum two strings and get an int value as result.
Why can't I simply subtract 48 to turn a char into an int value?

```
int AddOperator(char *a, char *b){

int sum = 0;
char i, j;
    if (strlen(a) >= strlen(b)){
        for(i=0, j=0; i < strlen(a); i++, j++)  
            sum += a[i-48]+b[j-48]; 
    }
    else if (strlen(b) > strlen(a)){
        for(i=0, j=0; i < strlen(b); i++, j++)  
            sum += a[i-48]+b[j-48]; 
    }
return sum;
```

Comment: You are subtracting from index do `a[i] - 48`

Comment: Or simply `while (*a && *b) { sum += *a - '0' + *b - '0'; a++, b++; }` (assuming strings `a` and `b` contain only digits, otherwise you need to add checks to confirm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
a[i] - '0'.
```

Also, in the first loop, where length of `a` is more then length of `b`, you will read values from `b` that don't exist. Similar situation in second loop however for `a`.

Comment: I see, you're right. In this case, I should better get a string as value and then convert it into an int.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum += a[i-48]+b[j-48];
```

should be

```
sum += (a[i]-48 +b[j]-48);
```

You should also fix the code as you are going beyond string length of smaller sring this could lead to undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

change

```
sum += a[i-48]+b[j-48];
```

to

```
sum += a[i] - '0' + b[j] - '0';
```

Comment: It's not `a[48]`

Comment: change _a[48] - '0'_ to _a[i] - '0'_

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to sum each corresponding character in *string a* and *string b* for each index where they contain digits, then you can do this very simply with pointer arithmetic for all common-indexes:

```
int addoperator (char *a, char *b)
{
    int sum = 0;

    while (*a && *b) {               /* so long as each contains digits */
        sum += *a - '0' + *b - '0';  /* sum the digits */
        a++, b++;                    /* increment pointers */
    }

    return sum;
}
```

**note:** the code above presumes only *digit* characters within strings `a` and `b`, otherwise add tests as required.

**Short Test Example**

```
int main (void) {

    char *a = "123456789", *b = "1234567";
    int sum = addoperator (a, b);

    printf ("sum: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/addchars
sum: 56
```

If you have any further questions, just let me know.